# Omniauth/Devise/Facebook: Auth route is not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, devise, omniauth

I've been working on this problem for 7 hours now, and I still have no idea. Maybe one of you can help me.

I'm simply trying to integrate the OAuth feature of Devise 1.2rc, which uses Omniauth, into my Rails application.

- I've been using this tutorial by Devise:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview

- I have done everything they tell you to...
- Yes, I have added the following line to my devise.rb:

`config.omniauth :facebook, "APP ID", "APP SECRET"`

- I have added :omniauthable to my user model, as well as the class function as described in the tutorial
- I have implemented the omniauth_callbacks controller, as well as the callback function, and I have specified the omniauth_callbacks controller in my routes.rb
- When I run "rake middleware" it does list the Omniauth middleware:

`use OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook`

- I have installed Devise directly from the Git repo, master branch, so it's up-to-date
- I have installed Omniauth 1.2.0.beta5, which is the latest version. In my Gemfile it says:

`gem 'oa-oauth', '0.2.0.beta5', :require => 'omniauth/oauth'`

- I have restarted the server, obviously
- However, when I try to request this URL:

`http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook`

it simply says

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/auth/facebook"):

/user/auth/facebook doesn't work either.

Since I unfortunately don't have the time to take apart the entire Omniauth and Devise gems and understand every line of code in them, maybe one of you could tell me what the problem might be.

Comment: Have you tried /users/auth/facebook

Comment: yes, doesn't work either. none of the routes even exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is solved now. Apparently it was a problem with Devise. I posted it as an issue on their Github and they fixed it in their source. In the latest Devise master branch it now works.

Answer (score 2):

After some hours trying to fix this issue I realized that i'd `config/initializers/omniauth.rb` in the `.gitignore` file (shame on me).

so remove omniauth.rb from the .gitignore list if you haven't already

Comment: There's no `config/initializers/omniauth.rb` when using the omniauthable module.

Comment: i use one to save the api keys, but certainly its not necessary